# AWS lambda log to cloudWatch, via console Yes, via api call NO

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cloudwatch

I set up API Gateway with Lambda function. If I run Lambda with 'test' button in console, console.log writes to CloudWatch fine. If I run http calls from Postman to Gateway then to Lambda, there is no logs.
Is this the way? If yes, how can the app log in production? I know the API gateway can log as well, but this way doesn't log the console.log in Lambda. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The behavior is the same, it doesn't matter how your AWS Lambda is invoked. Maybe your API Gateway is misconfigured? Do you point to a different AWS Lambda Version or a different Function?

Comment: Maybe the Lambda is in another region?

Answer (score 1):

MaiKaY's answer was correct. It was only I didn't 'deploy' API.  AWS way: configure, save, in the end we need to 'deploy'. Thank you all.